# Customize Google Plus One with Image

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I have implemented gplus button on the site, and it works perfect, but when I press it and go to my gplus account it shows me some random image form site page near the title. 
How can I set up the image in my gplus button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently impossible to customize it.